# show selected days on a button

Tags: datepicker, calendar, timepicker

I want to show selected days on a butoon (from.... -to .....) in calendar picker view. Here is my code

CalendarPickerView calendarView = binding.calendar;
// TextView time_TV = binding.time;

```
    calendarbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calendarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Date today = new Date();
            Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
            nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            calendarView.init(today, nextYear.getTime()).
                    inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE).
                    withSelectedDate(today);
            calendarView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
                    Calendar calenderSelected = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calenderSelected.setTime(date);


                    String selectedDate = " " + calenderSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            + " " + (calenderSelected.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            + " " + calenderSelected.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                            + " - " + calenderSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            + " " + (calenderSelected.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            + " " + calenderSelected.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    calendarbtn.setText(selectedDate);

                }

                @Override
                public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi @helen87, please make sure to format your code sample correctly (use the curly braces in editor toolbar) so it's easier for your peers to read your question.  Also you should add a little more text describing what you expect to achieve with your code versus what actually happens when you run it. And you might want to add some additional tags to classify your question. I assume "Java" and "Android" might fit.

Comment: When I click on a button, it opens calendar picker view, and than when I select dates it shows only last day of selected date. I want to show start date and end date, something like booking reservation.